# How to add a static map marker in the HERE maps Android sdk?

Tags: android, marker, here-api

I would like to make markers that doesn't move when the map rotates, exactly like the polylines. My goal is to give the marker a single orientation that never changes even when getsures occure.

I have tried with every marker type but I can't get the wanted effect.

Any kind of help would be appreciated since I am stuck here for really long hours

Comment: If I get this right, you want to avoid that the marker keeps rotating to face you, correct? I'm not sure you can do that with markers. The only thing I can think of right now would be using a [MapLocalModel](https://developer.here.com/mobile-sdks/documentation/android-hybrid-plus/topics_api_nlp_hybrid_plus/com-here-android-mpa-mapping-maplocalmodel.html). But then you have to supply the model and the texture yourself

Comment: Thank you ! I looked what you suggested, and it looks like it's the only way to accomplish what I want to do. However I find this really complex for such a simple thing ... HERE should really make this simpler like in google maps.  Now I have to understand how models and textures work .. Thanks anyway

Comment: The MapLocalModel is mostly for drawing complex textured or shaded objects. We use it to add fun things like cars and 3d objects into the map. Please use the MapMarker class as suggested in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can draw a simple rectangle with both front and back facing sides textured as follows:

```
    // Two triangles
    FloatBuffer buff = FloatBuffer.allocate(12);
    buff.put(0- delta);
    buff.put(0- delta);
    buff.put(1.f);

    buff.put(0 + delta);
    buff.put(0 - delta);
    buff.put(1.f);

    buff.put(0 - delta);
    buff.put(0 + delta);
    buff.put(1.f);

    buff.put(0 + delta);
    buff.put(0 + delta);
    buff.put(1.f);

    // Two triangles to generate the rectangle. Both front and back face
    IntBuffer vertIndicieBuffer = IntBuffer.allocate(12);
    vertIndicieBuffer.put(0);
    vertIndicieBuffer.put(2);
    vertIndicieBuffer.put(1);
    vertIndicieBuffer.put(2);
    vertIndicieBuffer.put(3);
    vertIndicieBuffer.put(1);
    vertIndicieBuffer.put(0);
    vertIndicieBuffer.put(1);
    vertIndicieBuffer.put(2);
    vertIndicieBuffer.put(1);
    vertIndicieBuffer.put(3);
    vertIndicieBuffer.put(2);

    // Texture coordinates
    FloatBuffer textCoordBuffer = FloatBuffer.allocate(8);
    textCoordBuffer.put(0.f);
    textCoordBuffer.put(0.f);
    textCoordBuffer.put(1.f);
    textCoordBuffer.put(0.f);
    textCoordBuffer.put(0.f);
    textCoordBuffer.put(1.f);
    textCoordBuffer.put(1.f);
    textCoordBuffer.put(1.f);

    // The LocalMesh itself.
    LocalMesh mesh = new LocalMesh();
    mesh.setVertices(buff);
    mesh.setVertexIndices(vertIndicieBuffer);
    mesh.setTextureCoordinates(textCoordBuffer);

    MapLocalModel model = new MapLocalModel();
    model.setMesh(mesh);
    model.setDynamicScalingEnabled(true);
    model.setAnchor(new GeoCoordinate(LATITUDE, LONGITUDE, 0.0));
```

Attach an image to it for texture, and use MapRenderLisener#onPredraw() to change the pitch and yaw of the local model object to follow the camera.

Comment: Thank yout this is exactly what I needed !

Comment: how we get local mesh import in android?

Comment: How to get exact orientation value for set yaw in MapLocalModel when the map in navigation?

Answer (score 0):

The [MapMarker](https://developer.here.com/mobile-sdks/documentation/android-hybrid-plus/topics_api_nlp_hybrid_plus/com-here-android-mpa-mapping-mapmarker.html) object is what you are looking for? It is anchored to the position you give it and it will always be drawn in screen 2d space regardless of the tilt and rotate you apply to the map.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Well, according to the link you just gave me, it's the opposite : " The map handles proper placement of icons on the screen as well as panning and rotation. " The MapMarker will rotate if the map rotates and I don't see any way to disable that ...

Comment: The MapMarker does not rotate, it is drawn in flat 2d screen space. I believe our documentation is a bit confusing in that sense. It should state it is "anchored" to a GeoCoordinate and is always front facing regardless of tilt or orientation of the map.

Comment: Yes that's it, it's always front facing, and I want a marker that won't do that, because I am trying to add a specific image with a specific angle (maybe I wasn't clear too) . If there is a way to do this without a MapLocalModel, please tell me how, I would really appreciate . Thanks

Comment: In this case, MapLocalModel is your best bet. I'll post a snippet of code to help you out.

Comment: What is the delta value of the above snippet?