# Nokia Here maps Navigation marker orientation

Tags: android, google-maps, navigation, maps, here-api

I am using here maps for Turn-by-Turn Navigation in Android. I want to set the orientation of the marker in Navigation with the device orientation, in other words, I want to put device orientation info into here maps.

Eg. My destination is towards east but I am facing west so Navigation should tell me to take 'U' turn and then proceed instead of start moving the pointer.

So is there any api in Nokia here maps which does this or here maps does this inside the sdk while initializing Navigation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HERE `MapMarker` API does not provide functions to do this directly. The `MapMarker` default behaviour is to orient itself automatically so that the marker image is always facing "up" on the screen (map). Currently this behaviour cannot be overridden.

One thing you can try is to rotate the actual `Image` you are adding to the `MapMarker` based on your requirements and update the `MapMarker` with the rotated `Image`.

Comment: Even though this is the accepted answer, please also see the link below posted by David Leong -- `MapLocalModel` is another good option.

Comment: I couldn't see any link in the comment above, could you please update?

Comment: @ravoorinandan Here's the link! https://stackoverflow.com/a/36731553/275524